# for loop showing RangeError flutter

Tags: flutter

The following code shows

```
E/flutter ( 7354): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..17: 18
E/flutter ( 7354): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:254:60)
E/flutter ( 7354): #1      parseStudent (package:xxx/screens/SearchActivity/main.dart:22:19)
E/flutter ( 7354): #2      _IsolateConfiguration.apply (package:flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart:81:34)
E/flutter ( 7354): #3      _spawn.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart:88:65)
E/flutter ( 7354): #4      _spawn.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart:87:5)
E/flutter ( 7354): #5      Timeline.timeSync (dart:developer/timeline.dart:163:22)
E/flutter ( 7354): #6      _spawn (package:flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart:85:35)
E/flutter ( 7354): #7      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:286:17)
E/flutter ( 7354): #8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
```

this error.

Code:

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(responseBody);
  List<dynamic> data = map["students"];
  //developer.log(data[0]);
  List<Student> stL = List<Student>();
  for(int i=0;data[i]!=null;i++){
    Student student = Student(rollno:data[i]["username"],name:data[i]["name"],
        hostel:data[i]["hostel"],room:data[i]["room"],gender:data[i]["gender"]);
    stL.add(student);
  }
  developer.log(stL.toString());
  return stL;
```

`developer.log()` is not called.Can someone give a solution?
Or is there a better way to parse the JSON to a list of `Student`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `List<dynamic>` use `Iterable`.

```
  Iterable list = map['students'];
  list.forEach((element){
    Student student = Student(rollno:element["username"],name:element["name"],
      hostel:element["hostel"],room:element["room"],gender:element["gender"]);
    stL.add(student);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

@Tipu solution is acceptable, but dart can provide more flexible way. You can also use the `from` named constructor of `List`.

```
List<Student> stL = List<Student>.from(map['students'].map((element) =>
        Student(rollno:element["username"],name:element["name"],
            hostel:element["hostel"],room:element["room"],gender:element["gender"])
    ).toList());
```

Comment: Flutter itself is using this method in many places in its code. I do not find any performance wise sentence from flutter. However, I observe it on large list in my project which is fixed in length, it provided me a better performance than `for` or `foreach` loops

Comment: Mine is a small(max 30 to 40) variable list and other one seems to be faster.